# Access the current database Connection object during a DbMigraiton

Tags: c#, entity-framework, entity-framework-6

I have a code-first Entity Framework context that needs to support both SQL Server and Oracle.

The model itself is fairly straightforward, except for a problem with multiple `CASCADE DELETE` paths in SQL Server that I want to resolve with a trigger.

I can create the trigger fine with the `SQL` method on `DbMigration`, but I'd like to only create the trigger if the database I'm migrating is actually a SQL Server database.

I'd like to do something like the following:-

```
public override void Up()
{

  ...

  if (this.Database.Connection.ProviderName == "System.Data.SqlClient")
  {
    this.CreateTable(...); // Create the table without CASCADE DELETE

    this.Sql(...); // Create the trigger
  }
  else if (this.Database.Connection.ProviderName == "Oracle.ManagedDataAccess.Client")
  {
    this.CreateTable(...); // Create the table with CASCADE DELETE
  }

  ...
}
```

My problem is that the `DbMigration` base class does not appear to provide any hook to interrogate the current database connection.

I can't interrogate the .config file via `ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings` because I'm likely to be overriding the connection string while using e.g. the `Update-Database` cmdlet.

Is there any way to interrogate the current database connection during a DbMigration? Are there any other hooks I could use?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For the benefit of future readers, I eventually resolved this issue for my own use-case (supporting both SQL Server and Oracle) by creating **two** data contexts with a shared interface for the same set of entities - one for SQL Server, and one for Oracle - detecting the ProviderName on the connection string, and injecting the appropriate context at runtime.

Not only did this let me maintain two sets of migrations with the database specific *behaviour*, it also allowed me to better support e.g. the naming conventions that our Oracle developers asked for, without imposing those conventions on our SQL Server deployments.